# Как вернуть "обычное" отображение окна эмулятора в Android Studio в отдельное окно с видом устройства?

Tags: android, интерфейс, эмулятор

После обновления Android Studio эмулятор стал открываться среди остальных окон проекта (рис. 1).
Не буду спорить об удобности, просто хотел спросить, как вернуть интерфейс к привычному виду?

[image: Как выглядит в Android Studio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Себе же на заметку.
[Оригинал вопроса-ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70986530/android-studio-emulator-in-a-separate-window)

Видимо, в обновленных версиях по умолчанию заданны другие настройки отбражения. Нужно просто вернуть всё как было

File - Settings - Tools - Emulator - Убрать галочку Launch in a tool window

[image: File - Settings]

[image: Tools - Emulator - Убрать галочку Launch in a tool window]

[image: Результат]